# How can i select dom when testing with jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

```js
it('render list',() => {
    const handleClick = jest.fn()
    const mockList = [{id:1011322,name:"Druig"},{id:1009284,name:"Dum Dum Dugan"},{id:101078,name:"Eddie Brock"}] 
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<AutoComplete match={mockList} className={"autocomplete-items"} onClick={handleClick}/>, div);
    debugger;
    expect(document.querySelectorAll(".autocomplete-items li").length).toBe(3);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  })
```

was not able to select the rendered dom with 
`document.querySelectorAll(".autocomplete-items li")`
when I debug `document.querySelectorAll(".autocomplete-items li")` it return a weird object. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the container element which your component rendered, the `div` element not `document`.

`index.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AutoComplete extends Component<any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className={this.props.className} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
          {this.props.match.map(item => {
            return <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AutoComplete;
```

`index.spec.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AutoComplete from './index';

describe('AutoComplete', () => {
  it('render list', () => {
    const handleClick = jest.fn();
    const mockList = [
      { id: 1011322, name: 'Druig' },
      { id: 1009284, name: 'Dum Dum Dugan' },
      { id: 101078, name: 'Eddie Brock' }
    ];
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<AutoComplete match={mockList} className={'autocomplete-items'} onClick={handleClick} />, div);
    expect(div.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete-items li').length).toBe(3);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58820204/index.spec.tsx (9.049s)
  AutoComplete
    ✓ render list (32ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.788s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58820204